# direction of friction between block and table

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

[image]

I don't really understand the free body diagram of the table, as in, why is the force of block B acting on the table directed in the direction of the pulling force.

Can you help me out with that?

Comment: Think a little more carefully about what the red arrow indicates.  It _isn't_ "the force of block B acting on the table".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Direction of Friction on two stacked boxes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362182/)

Answer (score 0):

There are only two forces acting on table:
1) The normal reaction by the combined system of A&B in the vertically downward direction.
2) Friction force acting in forward direction.

You seem to be having problem with the direction of second force. 
Remember friction always opposes relative slipping between surfaces. In case of combined system of A& B, the force of friction is acting in the backward direction because the relative movement of system ( A+B) is in forward direction but try to imagine taking velocity of system A+B zero, for there to be displacement of system w.r.t table, the table must have to move backward and as friction always opposes relative slip between surfaces, therefore friction is acting in forward direction.

Is that what you were asking? Hope I helped :)

Comment: My pleasure. I've learnt it pretty much recently. I'm too doing Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: Sorry, please check the answer again, I made the mistake of forward and backward in the last. I'd edited my answer now. I'm sorry.